# Memory leak issue while allocating memory to object

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-leaks

I am facing memory leak issue with very simple code.I have class 'TestClass'

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject
  @property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *name;
@end
```

its implementation is like this:

```
@implementation TestClass
@synthesize name;
-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.name = @"";
    }
    return self;
}
-(void) dealloc
{
    [name release];
    name = nil;
}
@end
```

There is another view controller inside viewWillAppear i am creating object and releasing immediately as follows

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    for (int i =0; i<50; i++) {
        TestClass *testClass = [[TestClass alloc] init] ;
        [testClass release];

    }
}
```

The leak instrument shows memory leak on line `TestClass *testClass = [[TestClass alloc] init] ;` while if i remove init and dealloc method from TestClass there is no memory.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you don't release the TestClass in the dealloc of its own implementation of dealloc:

```
-(void) dealloc
{
    [name release], name = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Also as a tip, I would suggest moving way from memory management code and moving to [`ARC`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Hi rckoenes thanks for reply. I found my mistake its because worong syntax of dealloc method inside TestClass. I m not calling [super dealloc]; Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What rckoenes is correct, but you can simply:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    self.name = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Don't use the `self.` syntax in the dealloc, It could really [mess things up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877071/using-setters-mutators-in-dealloc).